# Изменение данных полей таблицы

Tags: python, crm, python-2.7, erp, odoo

Есть [odoo](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDUQFjACahUKEwiP3Ynks-THAhWCD3IKHSmVBj4&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fodoo%2Fodoo&usg=AFQjCNEd33_QMTgqi4CdhboHVZzh3eUSBQ&sig2=jYX_z9Pdi__6ibDkIrRjcw) с самописным модулем табеля учёта рабочего времени. Колонки — дни месяца (1-31), строки — работники. На пересечении, соответственно, время прихода на работу.

Но разные люди, ответственные за заполнение, заполняют по-разному. Одни заполняют время в стандартном формате `ЧЧ:ММ` (к примеру, `10:08`), а другие используют десятые доли (к примеру `10,125`, что означает те же `10:08`). Посему потребовалось написать функцию, реализовывающую конвертацию с долей в стандартный формат.

Функция написана, работает. Но я уверен, что можно её оптимизировать. Как минимум, ту часть, где перечисляются колонки.

Спасибо за внимание.

```
@api.one
def time_button (self):
    def ftohhmm(a):
       if a:
          a = re.sub(',' , '.' , a)
          if (re.search ('^\-?\d+((,|\.)\d+)?$',a) >= 0): 
             if float(a) <24: 
                a = float(a) * 60
                minutes = a%60
                hours = a/60
                if int(round(minutes)) < 10:
                   return str(int(hours))+":0"+str(int(round(minutes)))
                else:
                   return str(int(hours))+":"+str(int(round(minutes)))
       return a
    if self.format:
       for i in self.ids_string:
          i.hours1=ftohhmm(i.hours1)
          i.hours2=ftohhmm(i.hours2)
          i.hours3=ftohhmm(i.hours3)
          i.hours4=ftohhmm(i.hours4)
          i.hours5=ftohhmm(i.hours5)
          i.hours6=ftohhmm(i.hours6)
          i.hours7=ftohhmm(i.hours7)
          i.hours8=ftohhmm(i.hours8)
          i.hours9=ftohhmm(i.hours9)
          i.hours10=ftohhmm(i.hours10)
          i.hours11=ftohhmm(i.hours11)
          i.hours12=ftohhmm(i.hours12)
          i.hours13=ftohhmm(i.hours13)
          i.hours14=ftohhmm(i.hours14)
          i.hours15=ftohhmm(i.hours15)
          i.hours16=ftohhmm(i.hours16)
          i.hours17=ftohhmm(i.hours17)
          i.hours18=ftohhmm(i.hours18)
          i.hours19=ftohhmm(i.hours19)
          i.hours20=ftohhmm(i.hours20)
          i.hours21=ftohhmm(i.hours21)
          i.hours22=ftohhmm(i.hours22)
          i.hours23=ftohhmm(i.hours23)
          i.hours24=ftohhmm(i.hours24)
          i.hours25=ftohhmm(i.hours25)
          i.hours26=ftohhmm(i.hours26)
          i.hours27=ftohhmm(i.hours27)
          i.hours28=ftohhmm(i.hours28)
          i.hours29=ftohhmm(i.hours29)
          i.hours30=ftohhmm(i.hours30)
          i.hours31=ftohhmm(i.hours31)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно переписать в виде цикла:

```
for j in range(1, 32):
    hours = 'hours{0}'.format(j)
    setattr(i, hours, ftohmm(getattr(i, hours)))
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Надеюсь, кому-нибудь однажды поможет тоже.